# MongoDB Operation Not Permitted

Tags: mongodb, server, vps

MongoDB was working perfectly until one day it generated a lock file and stopped starting with the following error:

```
16-12-28T17:50:14.559+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-12-28T17:50:14.559+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian71
2016-12-28T17:50:14.559+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-12-28T17:50:14.559+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-12-28T17:50:14.559+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-12-28T17:50:14.577+0100 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2016-12-28T17:50:14.577+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2016-12-28T17:50:14.577+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2016-12-28T17:50:14.577+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2016-12-28T17:50:14.577+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1024M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-12-28T17:50:14.590+0100 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1482943814:590694][32048:0x7f27c7cdcc80], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2016-12-28T17:50:14.591+0100 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:1: Operation not permitted src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 267
2016-12-28T17:50:14.591+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 1: Operation not permitted, terminating
2016-12-28T17:50:14.591+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2016-12-28T17:50:14.591+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2016-12-28T17:50:14.591+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2016-12-28T17:50:14.591+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2016-12-28T17:50:14.591+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

I have removed all packages and reinstalled all of the mongodb services with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming permissions are correct. It could be an selinux issue, try:

```
setenforce 0
```

then try to start the server. If the server starts, you will have to use semanage to set the proper context to the mongo data folder

Comment: @EricRich even if there is no other option because 3rd-party tools will not work otherwise?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum my answer focused on diagnosing the issue. if your system works with selinux in non enforcing mode, you might have to change the context of the data folder and its contents with chcon to change context, semanage to make policy changes or use audit2allow on security logs to generate rules for you. The video goes into how to use some of those tools but there are plenty of how tos which will show you how to generate a policy or at least set your application (like mongo) in permisssive mode - where everything except that application is unbound

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

sudo chown -R ﻿⁠⁠⁠⁠id -u﻿⁠⁠⁠⁠ /data/db

Comment: yes I have made mongod the owner of the folder and have even tried making all the files read write.

Comment: Make sure you do not have a mongod instance running.

See if there is an instance running in the background by running the this command : ps aux | grep mongo

if there is like : 24337 bla bla mongod

do: kill 24337

and then yo might be able to run it fine.